# How to pass a reference to an object to another class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass a reference to an object from my main.cpp to menux.cpp however I'm getting this error:

error: conflicting declaration 'MenuX alpha4'
MenuX(alpha4);

main.cpp

```
#include "MenuX.h"
Adafruit_AlphaNum4 alpha4 = Adafruit_AlphaNum4();
MenuX(alpha4);
```

MenuX.h

```
#ifndef MENUX_H
#define MENUX_H

#include "Adafruit_LEDBackpack.h"
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h> // Core graphics library

class MenuX
{
public:
    MenuX(Adafruit_AlphaNum4 *alpha4);
    void addX();

private:
    Adafruit_AlphaNum4 *xLed;
};

#endif
```

MenuX.cpp

```
#include "MenuX.h"

MenuX::MenuX(Adafruit_AlphaNum4 *alpha4) {
    xLed = alpha4;
}
void MenuX::addX()
{
    xLed->writeDigitAscii(0, 'X');
    xLed->writeDigitAscii(1, 'X');
    xLed->writeDigitAscii(2, 'X');
    xLed->writeDigitAscii(3, 'X');
    xLed->writeDisplay();
}
```

Comment: Your constructor takes a pointer but in main.cpp alpha4 isn't a pointer

Comment: when i try this still still doesnt work:

Adafruit_AlphaNum4 *alpha4 = &Adafruit_AlphaNum4();
MenuX(*alpha4);

Comment: Just pass in the address
Adafruit_AlphaNum4 alpha4 = Adafruit_AlphaNum4();
MenuX(&alpha4);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You don't have your main code inside of a main function
- You can create the `alpha4` in main without creating and assigning a temporary
- The MenuX constructor takes a pointer so you need to pass `&alpha4`
- Not an error but probably a mistake, you don't use the MenuX you've created

```
#include "MenuX.h"

int main() {
    Adafruit_AlphaNum4 alpha4;
    MenuX menu(&alpha4);  // added & and object name
}
```